# Live videoediting for Google Hangout

Tags: webcam, video-streaming, obs-studio

I need to edit the video recorded by my webcam "on the fly" and to stream it to a Google Hangouts call. What I want to do is to remove the background of the video (and possibly substitute it with an image), so that the other participants can't see what's happening behind me. Is that possible?

I found that [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) can do that, but it looks like Google Hangouts streaming isn't supported. I found a plugin that creates something like a "virtual cam" ([OBS Virtualcam | OBS Forums](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.949/)), but it isn't avilable for Ubuntu.

Any solution is good for me, but I would much prefer FOSS-only ones.